# Are there infinitely many primes of form $\underbrace{3\dots3}_n{}1$?

Tags: proof-writing, prime-numbers, recreational-mathematics

The following numbers are prime:

$ 31 $

 $ 331 $

 $ 3331 $

 $ 33331 $

 $ 333331 $

 $ 3333331 $

 $ 33333331 $

Which made me think, is there something we can use to prove/disprove the statement that there are infinitely many primes of this form?

> More precisely, can we prove/disprove that there are infinitely many
>   primes of form:
>
> $$\frac{10^{n+1}-7}{3}$$

This is prime for $n=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,17,39,49,59\dots$ since I tested all $n\le60$

---

The only proofs for "*infinitely many primes of form X*" I know of are using the [Dirichlet's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions), but I don't see that it would be helpful in cases like this one.

Comment: This seems no easier than the question: are there infinitely many primes of the form $2^n-1$?  And that one is a known open question.

Comment: This page will help: http://stdkmd.com/nrr/3/33331.htm

Comment: Just for trivia, it was proved (in 1997) that there are infinitely many primes of the form $x^2+y^4$ also. It's called the  Friedlander-Iwaniec theorem. However, no results come even close to the kind of result you are asking for.

Comment: Another open problem that looks even easier is whether $x^2+1$ is prime for infinite many positive integers $x$. More general, no polynomial with integer coefficients and degree greater than $1$ is known to produce infinite many primes.

Comment: See https://oeis.org/A055520

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A proof that there are infinite many primes of this form seems to be out of reach, but since the sequence is not increasing very fast and the $gcd$ of the numbers seems to be $1$, there are probably infinite many. The first few $n$ giving proven primes , calculated with PARI/GP are :

```
? for(n=1,500,m=(10^(n+1)-7)/3;if(isprime(m,2)==1,print1(n," ")))
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 17 39 49 59 77 100 150 318 381
?
```

You can also look up the known primes in this superb factorization database :

http://factordb.com/index.php?query=%2810%5E%28n%2B1%29-7%29%2F3&use=n&n=1&sent=Show&VP=on&VC=on&EV=on&OD=on&PR=on&PRP=on&U=on&perpage=20&format=1

Comment: The database approves that $n=783,1731$ and $1917$ give the next primes coinciding with my pseudoprime-rotuine PARI/GP giving the same values.

Comment: Note that the `isprime` test is not pseudo

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen isprime(n,2) proves the prime and isprime gives a "very probable" prime. But for numbers with more than $500$ digits it is generally quite slow.

Comment: Hm, according to what my PARi tells me in documentation, the result of `isprime` is *always* based on proven primality or compositeness, no matter if/what you have as second parameter (hough the proof may not always be output). Only `ispseudoprime` test for "very probable" prime ..

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Not quite , isprime is based on a combined lucas-test and strong probable prime test with base $2$, which is conjectured to be sufficient to prove primality (but there might be counterexamples). It has been checked that the routine is correct upto $2^{64}$, if I remember right.

Comment: It is well possible that this has been changed and the newest version is different.

Comment: Minor quibble, but I would say the sequence is growing quite rapidly. It is, after all, growing exponentially. The thinness of this sequence is a major obstacle to detecting prime values.

Comment: $$\large \frac{10^{8854+1}-7}{3}$$ is probable prime.

Comment: Since this question won't get an answer with a proof unless there is some significant breakthrough,  I'll accept this answer.