# Are there an infinite number of primes of the form 133...331?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

The first 5 primes of this form are of lengths 3, 5, 7, 95, and 161 (131, 13331, 1333331, etc.). Can it be shown there are an infinite number of primes with form 133...331? Can it be shown there are only a finite number of them?

Comment: I doubt it highly.

Comment: I have only been able to determine a [pattern](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3462899/prove-that-numbers-of-the-form-131-1331-13331-are-divisible-by-19-when-th) for factors 11 and 19.

Comment: It was only recently shown that there are infinitely many primes without a 7, or any other single digit (within the last few years, in a paper by Maynard) and as far as I know there wouldn’t yet be a proof that you have infinitely many that use only 1 and 3. For these guys in particular maybe there is a proof of finitely many, but if not then the problem is open.

Comment: The closed formula for this is $\frac{4\cdot 10^n-7}{3}.$

Comment: @guy This is already remarkable , but still far away from solving questions like this.

Comment: Surely, someone has checked those numbers upto a very large $\ n\ $

Comment: Heuristically, infinite many such prime exist. A quite large has $\ 2899\ $ digits. Incredibly , factordb claims it to be proven prime by the $p+1$ - method.

Comment: First $n$ , for which Thomas Andrews's expression is (probably) prime : 1 2 4 6 94 160 360 1470 2898 3094 3112

Comment: Just found another PRP ( $\ n=15699\ $ )

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2226024/are-there-infinitely-many-primes-of-form-underbrace3-dots3-n1?rq=1) is a related post. I wonder if these types of generalized Mersenne numbers have been looked at more closely?

Comment: @Peter Thanks for extending the search! Could you elaborate on what the p+1 method is?

Comment: @Peter See OEIS sequence [A082697](http://oeis.org/A082697)

Comment: @Goldbug A primality proving method based on the factorization of $\ p+1\ $ , if $\ p\ $ has to be proven prime. I am astonished however that this was possible for the huge prime.

Comment: @Peter I was curious if perhaps there was some reason why this p+1 method was easy to use on a number of this form... It seems there might be if you were astonished?

Comment: @Goldbug  Usually, we need the prime factorization of $p+1$ or at least a sufficient partial factorization.

Comment: @Peter Could the p+1 method be easier because $133...331+1=133...332=3*4*11...111$? I know repunits are easier to factor than the average number.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101888/discussion-between-peter-and-goldbug).

Comment: 2,3,5,7 can't divide ( okay 7 maybe but not more than 1 in 6 terms). So that makes smaller values more likely to produce primes.

Comment: length can't be 4 mod 16 for divisibility by 17 it looks like.